# Laravel Job Is not deleted after process

Tags: php, laravel, email, jobs

this is my scenario: I have a Laravel queued jod, here the handle method content:

```
$invoiceContract = app('AsteBolaffi\Repositories\Backend\Invoice\InvoiceContract');

$error = $invoiceContract->recordInvoice($this->invoiceId);
d($error);
if (!empty($error) && !empty($this->userEmail)) {
    $userEmail = $this->userEmail;
    $invoice = $invoiceContract->findOrThrowException($this->invoiceId);
    $invoice->load('customer');
    d("Going to send mail to " . $userEmail);
    d($error);
    d($invoice->customer->business_name);
    $data["error"] = $error;
    $data["business_name"] = $invoice->customer->business_name;
    $data["document_number"] = $invoice->document_number;
    d($data);
    \Mail::queueOn('mail', "emails.record_invoice", $data, function ($message) use ($userEmail) {
        $message->from('admin@astebolaffi.it', 'AsteBolaffi');
        $message->to($userEmail);
        $message->subject('Errori contabilizzazione fattura');
        d("HERE I AM");
    });
    d("Completed");
}
return;
```

If the recordInvoice method returns a value (e.g. "Item not found") the if clause is satisfied and it has to add a mail queue. But the mail queue is not created on db and the current job is not deleted even if the console prints the last d method value ("Completed").
If recordInvoice does not returns any error the job is deleted.

**Non-sense thing (at least for me)**

If I comment the recordInvoice method and set a value to error, for example:

```
$error = "test";
```

It works properly, adds the mail queue and deletes the current one.

Any tip about it?

Comment: I'd remove the `d()` statements, as that kills the script. If you want to log progress, use `Log::info()` instead, which will send what you want to the Laravel log file.

Comment: @aynber I've already tried and  as far as I know is the ddd command that kills script

Comment: You can use ShouldQueue interface to make your mails use queue.

Comment: @Kyslik my class already implements ShouldQueue, all my other jobs works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but moving the project from php 5.6 to 7.0 it works correctly.